# How to deal with stupid designed databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So we just started doing web application for company X. Application have to calculate a lot of information like workers done job, how long he worked, how long device worked, device speed, device quality, parts quality, up-time, downtime, running time, waste and etc... etc... The problem is database is stupidly designed, no IDs(I joining it on multiple columns, but it's so slow), a lot of calculations inside view tables, (i am going to dream nightmares about this) database have a lot of and I mean a lot of tables with millions of records. So my question is how to approach this situation? Try to get the grip of database and try to do my job, even if it takes half a year to make everything work? Or maybe they should hire some database designer and change whole system...(but i guess they will not going to even if i ask to). Is there a software to fast get grip of database I could use? They using Microsoft Server SQL 2012.

P.S. Don't judge my English writing skills, i don't compile it very often.

EDIT:
 1. There is no integrity between some tables, so i have to work my way around. And server always busy and crashes from time to time. Sometimes it takes 20min to get 1000 row from view table. 2. Some expensive query executed every time i query something.

EDIT:
 There is a lot of data repeated in different tables.

EDIT:
Is there way to make database more efficient?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown lets not encourage this place to become reddit.  This is a professional site.

Comment: *joining it on multiple columns* You mean composite keys?

Comment: I would suggest extracting the data and importing it into a new proper built database Build your data upon this?

Comment: @Woot4Moo sorry can't restrain myself.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown it is ok, I forgive you :)

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: None of the reasons you stated (no IDs, lots of calculations inside views, lots of tables with millions of rows) is a reason to conclude that the database is stupidly designed. You'll have to show us a better example. How about including 2-3 CREATE table statements in the question?

Comment: Treat the customer database as an external interface and import any data you need into your application database.

Comment: _"Is there a software to fast get grip of database I could use?"_ If there was such a tool, I'd like to be on the selling side please ;) But seriously, _stupid design_ is not an argument, it's an allegation. Not everything we don't like or disagree with is actually stupid.

Comment: Among the reasons you cite that you think the database is bad are several (many narrow tables, calculation logic encapsulated in views) which, instead, argue that it's well designed.  As requested, I won't judge your English writing skills, but I think your database skills might possibly benefit by some study.

Comment: This belongs on [programmers.se] or maybe even [workplace.se] or [dba.se].

Comment: Dam i didn't even known there is such thing as Database Administrators forum. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through each point here:

> no IDs(I joining it on multiple columns, but it's so slow)

Do you actually mean you have no referential integrity between tables and there are no columns that would form a primary key?  If that is what you mean than yes I agree a non-normalized table is quite bad.  However, if there is referential integrity (which I would presume there is, this is not an issue).  You proceed to say it is slow, define slow.  If it takes 10 seconds to query over 2 trillion records, I would hardly call that slow.  If however, if takes 10 seconds to query over 5 rows, than yes that is slow.

> a lot of calculations inside view tables

Now is this a materialized view?  Meaning that the calculation is only executed once and the table is built off of that expensive query?  Or do you mean some expensive query is executed every time that it is targeted?  In the latter case that is bad, in the former that is correct.

> database have a lot of and I  mean a lot of tables with millions of
>   records

And your point is?  Millions of records in 2013 are not that many.  Further, if you are melting down over millions of records, it may be time to hang it up.  There will only be more data, barring some insane magnetic storm that destroys all technology as we know it.

> So my question is how to approach this situation?

Learn set theory and relational design.

Comment: 1. There is no integrity between some tables, so i have to work my way around. And server always busy and crashes from time to time. Sometimes it takes 20min to get 1000 row from view table.
2. No, it's not. Some expensive query executed every time i query something.

Comment: @willCodeForBeer ok this is helpful information.  Can you update your original question with these types of details so we can reopen it?  As it stands now we don't have enough specific information to help you.

Comment: @willCodeForBeer I agree with Woot4Moo. If you put arguments, facts, measurements and examples (even a part of the actual design/data) in your question, this may very well become a _very interesting_ subject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that changing the database is not trivial. What you need to do is understand this database structure well. Chances are you are not happy with it because you don't know it well. If you get to understand it, you can design views and canned queries for common every day tasks. Once you are comfortable with the database, you could then begin to make a list of what is wrong with the current design and what the business needs are. May be then you could draft a version 1.0 ERD and estimate the cost of building the new system based on business needs and your expertise in the current system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, contrary to popular belief, missing artificial keys do not automatically make a database "stupidly designed".

So yes, you should try to get the grip of database and try to do your job. Even if it takes you half a year to make everything work, it will probably still be cheaper than adapting the application that generates the data.

Whether your system can be improved by modifying the database can only be determined with an analysis by an expert. It is out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the BD structure is really as bad as you think. Perhaps there is some logic to the design you have missed? Better to check, it will save you time in the long run.
Also, is the database normalised? If there is a lot of data repeated in various tables, then it's not. If there is some attempt to normalise the database (minimising data duplication), then there is some intelligence in the design. Otherwise, you might be right.

Comment: There is a lot of, and i mean a lot of data repeated in various tables.

Comment: @willCodeForBeer That's a serious argument _in favor of the stupid-ish allegation_. Put it in your question!